# Prevent JaxB Gradle Plugin in Dependent Project From Referencing Current Java Project Directory

Tags: java, gradle, xsd, jaxb

I have two Java projects that uses Gradle for building, Project A & Project B.

In Project A, the build.grade is using JaxB to generate Java classes from an XSD file. I am using the jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin which requires defining the XSD directory.

## Project A

### build.grade

```
jaxb {
  xsdDir 'src/main/xsd'
...
```

If I run the build, Project A generates the Java classes and compiles fine.

For Project B, I want to use the Java generated classes in Project A so I added the project as a dependency.

## Project B

### settings.gradle

```
include ':project-a'
project(':project-a').projectDir = new File("../project-a")
```

### build.grade

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":project-a")
}
```

Now here is the problem, when I run the build for Project B, I get the following error:
`> Directory 'C:\Users\xxxx\eclipse-workspace\project-b\src\main\xsd' specified for property 'schemasDirectory' does not exist.` For some reason, it's using the Project B's directory as the root instead of Project A's which contains the XSD file.

My question is 1) Is there a way to avoid using Project B as the directory or 2) did I not structure my projects properly?